# How can I only send the changes in a string and reconstruct the string from those changes?

Tags: image, encoding, character-encoding, compression, base64

I want to send an image encoded in a string to a client application every second; let's say this image is being generated from a webcam(this is just an example).

However, the image isn't going to change significantly most of the time and I would prefer to only send the changes in the image in order to save on bandwidth.

So I'm thinking that I will send "keyframes" on connection and periodically, which will be the full image, but in between those keyframes I would like to only send the differences.  I think this should be possible since the image is a very small bitmap so it should be possible to reconstruct a new frame based on a previous frame and change data.

What is a way to do this?  Example implementations in any language are welcome.

SUMMARY: What I want to do is implement [P-frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types#Summary) with encoded frames.  Let's assume that these hypothetical strings represent a raw bitmap.  A satisfactory example could use a black and white image encoded as a string of zeros and ones. (ex. "101110010101010001110001010101...")  A 0 could represent a black pixel and 1 could represent a white pixel.

Comment: Don't use base64, and don't make up your own thing. Use video.

Comment: @Matt Ball Thank you for your suggestion.  However, I cannot use video and I do things like this because I enjoy learning.  If I could use video, I'd already use FFmpeg.